# Window object cleared on $Interval

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, blackberry-10, intervals

I'm experiencing rather weird behavior when trying to log a window object defined by `$window.open()` in AngularJS within an `$interval`

```
self = this
$scope.childWindow = $window.open(authService.buildAuthorizeUrl(), '_blank')
console.log $scope.childWindow
var1 = "I may not work"
self.var2 = 'I should work'
privateData.authInterval = $interval ->
  console.log $scope.childWindow
  console.log var1
  console.log self.var2
,
  1000
```

Output

```
Window {document: document, window: Window, frameElement: null, clientInformation: Navigator, onhashchange: null…}
Window {}
I may not work
I should work
Window {}
I may not work
I should work
```

As you can see, the first `console.log $scope.childWindow` is outputting a fully defined window object.  All others, inside the `$interval`, are outputting only `{}`.  I've tried not attaching `childWindow` to the `$scope` object, and I've tried attaching it to `self`.  I've also tried following [this](https://github.com/blackberry/BB10-WebWorks-Samples/blob/master/OAuth-Facebook/www/js/app.js#L111-L127) example too and experienced the same behavior.  Anyone have any idea why this is happening?  Thanks much.

JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/15124/

Comment: I'm not getting this same result. Do you have an example on jsfiddle/codepen/plnkr?

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle I made: http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/15124/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned this shouldn't work in the browser because of security reasons, which may explain why it's getting "overwritten." The use case of this was actually in a Blackberry10 Cordova application.  To fix this, you must disable web security in `config.xml` like so:

```
<access origin="*"/>
<preference name="websecurity" value="disable" />
```

Of course the `*` will whitelist all domains.  To tighten security down a bit, add domains you'd like to whitelist.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code in a browser and while setting a debug point inside the $interval function an empty object is getting logged in the console but the watch inspector on the right shows that $scope.childWindow is not empty. So you might just be able to use $scope.childWindow.

[image]

Comment: I tried inspecting it as well, and found a similar result.  My end goal is to grab the location of the `childWindow` by using `$scope.childWindow.window.location.href`, but that doesn't seem to be happening.  Location is defined, but I can't tell what its properties are.  [These](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp) are the properties apparently, but they're not available either. Weird stuff.